# Is there a way to query documents in mongoDB/mongoose to match ALL objects in an array property WHERE the datetime is greater than a specified date

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
const CourseSchema = new Schema({
  course_name: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
  },
  Course_Runs: [
    {
      run_id: {
        type: String,
      },
      // This field is for Teachers that are involved in the course run
      teachers: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "users" }],
      // Course Date Duration will be an inferred field from first session and last session
      Sessions: [{
          session_start_datetime: {
            type: Date,
          },
          session_end_datetime: {
            type: Date,
          },
       ]
   }]
}
```

Above is a snippet of the Schema

I want to be able to get documents where ALL Sessions object has a session_start_datetime greater than a specified date such as current date.

Answer (score 0):

```
YOURMODEL.find( { Sessions: { $all: [{session_start_datetime: {$gte: YOUR_DATE}] } } )
```

don't forget to pass YOUR_DATE in a correct Date format or it will not work.

example if your date is a string:

```
YOURMODEL.find( { Sessions: { $all: [{session_start_datetime: {$gte: new Date(YOUR_DATE)}] } } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
model.find({
    'Course_Runs.Sessions.session_start_datetime': {
        $gt: current_date
    }
})
```